# How do I do this search and order_by on a DBIx::Class::ResultSet

Tags: perl, dbix-class

**Problem definition.**

I have multiple clients with multiple users. Each client needs to be able to associate custom data with a user, search, and order by.

---

**Database Solution:**

A table `Customfields` which defines the `customfields` table. It has an `id` and `name`.
It has a has_many relationship with a `Userfields` table (aka "attributes").

The `Userfields` table has a `userid`, `customfieldid`, `content` and `id`.
It belongs_to a `Useraccounts` table (aka "useraccount") and `Customfields` (aka "customfield")

---

**Proposed select statement that I want:**

This is a select statement that achieves and produces what I need.

```sql
SELECT ua.*, (
    SELECT content FROM Userfields uf
    INNER JOIN Customfields cf
        ON cf.id = uf.customfieldid
    WHERE cf.name = 'Mothers birthdate'
    AND uf.uid=ua.uid
) AS 'Mothers birthdate',
    (
    SELECT content FROM Userfields uf
    INNER JOIN Customfields cf
        ON cf.id = uf.customfieldid
    WHERE cf.name = 'Join Date' AND
    uf.uid=ua.uid
) AS 'Join Date'
FROM UserAccounts ua
ORDER BY 'Mothers birthdate';
```

In this case their could be anything from 0 ... *x* sub SELECT statements in the select statement and any one of them or none of them could be wanting to be ordered by.

---

**Question**

How do I achieve this with a `->search` on my DBIx-Class resultset or how do I achieve the same result with a `->search` on my DBIx-Class resultset?

Here is how I usually select from my `Useraccounts` table, although I am unsure how to do the complex statement that I want to from here.

```perl
my @users = $db->resultset('Useraccounts')->search(
    undef,
    {
        page        => $page,
        join        => 'attributes',
        ...
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really pretty hairy, and any solution isn't going to be pretty, but it *does* look to be possible if you bend the rules a little bit. Forgive any mistakes I make, as I didn't go and create a schema to test this on, but it's based on the best info I have (and much help from ribasushi).

First, (assuming that your userfields table has a belongs_to relation with the customfields table, called `customfield`)

```
my $mbd = $userfields_rs->search(
    {
      'customfield.name' => 'Mothers birthdate',
      'uf.uid' => \'me.uid' # reference to outer query
    },
    {
      join => 'customfield',
      alias => 'uf', # don't shadow the 'me' alias here.
    }
)->get_column('content')->as_query;

# Subqueries and -as don't currently mix, so hack the SQL ourselves
$mbd->[0] .= q{ AS 'Mothers Birthdate'};
```

The literal `me.uid` that uf.uid is being matched against is an unbound variable -- it's the `uid` field from the query that we're eventually going to put this query into as a subselect. By default DBIC aliases the table that the query is addressing to `me`; if you gave it a different alias then you would use something diferent here.
Anyway, You could repeat this `as_query` business with as many different fields as you like, just varying the field-name (if you're smart, you'll write a method to generate them), and put them in an array, so now let's suppose that `@field_queries` is an array, containing `$mbd` above as well as another one based on Join Date, and anything you like.

Once you have that, it's as "simple" as...

```
my $users = $useraccounts_rs->search(
    { }, # any search criteria can go in here,
    {
      '+select' => [ @field_queries ],
      '+as' => [qw/mothers_birthdate join_date/], # this is not SQL AS
      order_by => {-asc => 'Mothers birthdate'},
    }
);
```

which will include each of the subqueries into the select.

Now for the sad part: as of right now, this whole thing actually *won't* work, because subqueries with placeholders don't work properly. So for now you need an additional workaround: instead of `'customfield.name' => 'Mothers birthdate'` in the subselect search, do `'customfield.name' => \q{'Mothers birthdate'}` -- this is using literal SQL for the field name (**BE CAREFUL** of SQL injection here!), which will sidestep the placeholder bug. But in the not-too-distant future, that bug will be resolved and the code above will work okay, and we'll update the answer to let you know that's the case.

See DBIx::Class::ResultSource [order_by documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/RIBASUSHI/DBIx-Class-0.082841/lib/DBIx/Class/ResultSet.pm#order_by)

Comment: Two points to this.
1) ->get_column('content')->as_query; returns a reference to a reference of an array not the expected reference to an array, this may well be a bug in my current dbix::class but I couldn't see any fixes mentioned in the changelog and the documentation seems to suggest this is expected behavior! I solved this by doing
${$userfields_rs->search(...)}
2) I solved the placeholder issue by adding 
 'bind' => $mbd->[1]
to my ->search.

After much playing this morning it all works :)

Comment: slight problem if I call ->paging on the resultset, I can't get ->total_entries out of it, looks like it grabs the placeholders that it doesn't need and appends them to the end, which causes an err. for now getting around that with an eval, but it's ugly.